# PHP WebSocket cannot connect to remote server

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I've set up a simple PHP WebSocket chat application.
In localhost is running well, in the server I use either "127.1.0.0" or "0.0.0.0" as host and a random number higher than 1024 as port.
In the client I set the same host and port and everything works.

If I try to do the same with a remote server it doesn't work. In the remote server I don't change the host, in the client I set the host of the server, for example "123.4.5.6:12345". I run the server file using php and it notifies me "Listening on: 127.0.0.1:12345". The client does not connect, should I also set the folder where the server file is? The IP to which folder of the linux server does it point?
Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: Check your firewalls, of course.  Also, server's listen address should not be 127.0.0.1 unless you explicitly want to disallow all remote traffic to that server. Most people want 0.0.0.0, which means to listen to all IP addresses.  Client should use the server's public IP, or even better the domain name.

Comment: I've tried to disable firewalls and I've tried to use 0.0.0.0 on the server side...Still not connecting...